# C# how to escape eval <%?

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I have such code:

```
<%# (int)Eval("Favorites") > 0 ? "<a href=\"history.aspx?visitorid=<%# Eval(\"VisitorID\") %\">Favorites</a> / " : ""%>
```

where I show a link if value>0 .. However it gives me a bad url(history.aspx?visitorid=%3C%#%20Eval) when I put visitorID=<%#...%>inside another Eval<%#..%>

how to escape this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the second Eval called if you code it like this:

```
<%# (int)Eval("Favorites") > 0 ? "<a href=\"history.aspx?visitorid=" + Eval("VisitorID") + "\">Favorites</a> / " : ""%>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could seperate that string, like this:

```
?visitorid=<" + "%# Eval(\"Visit
```

Comment: didnt work..still get the same wrong link history.aspx?favs=1&visitorid=%3C%#%20Eval(

Answer (score 0):

As your strings get more complex, you'll find it's easier to build them using static methods in your code behind.  Then in your ASPX you'll have something simple like <%# GetLink(Eval("VisitorId")) %>

Comment: You should just not do it in the ASPX page to begin with.